Printztronic on modern TV
I have been provided with a Printztronic Videosport 800 to try and get working.
New batteries and plugged in via COAX triggers a TV response, but I only have a couple of smart TVs which are not easy to tune for the Prinztronic video signal.
Can modern TVs handle such a device (ie. I need to make more effort in tuning,) or should I try and get my hands on an older display device?
Added from comments:

UK based.
Response was beeping as the TV auto-scanned frequencies.

I may just have to hit the charity shops for an old CRT.

What modern TV can interpret an analogue signal over coax?

@dave Still get aerial connectors, and the TVs I have are recent and have analogue options. They are programmed with auto-tune ony though.

https://www.google.com/search?q=Do+TVs+still+have+coax+input%3F

Mere presence of a coax connector says nothing about the encoding of the signal.  Before 2009: analogue NTSC. After: digital ATSC.  There's no point in a TV sold in the US today having an NTSC tuner since there are no NTSC broadcasts.  But I assumed you are US-based, this might affect any answer.  Since you say 'aerial' and not 'antenna', I guess not US.

@dave my modern LCD TV can... and you can still easily buy them, at least in Europe.

@dirkt I’m pretty sure Prinztronic is a British brand, where analogue broadcasts ceased in 2012 so it’s perfectly possible that an aerial input is for Freeview (i.e. digital) transmissions only.

@Tommy - you are right; it was the in-house brand for Dixons.

@dave I think the Sony 55" in my living room is about five years old.  It still has both RGB and RF inputs for NTSC signal.  I've actually connected both an Atari pinball game and an an atrari 2600 (although the latter has a loose connection I need to fix in the rca cable, and is rather fuzzy and without color.  I think, though, that I can send in color composite through one of the RGB inputs, so I may just bypass the modulator)

My LG smart TV has an option "digital only scan" which is enabled by default and means it doesn't add any analogue channels it finds. There is still a pause when it finds an analogue signal and tries to parse it, only it then moves on. I would need to disable this option to get it to add an analogue channel. Do your TVs have a similar option? Also - are you unplugging the aerial and ONLY connecting your device? I think channel 36 which used to be used for these devices is now used by a digital multiplex so that would interfere.


New batteries and plugged in via COAX triggers a TV response

What kind of response? At least on analog devices, when you plug in a modulated RF signal and are on the wrong channel, the image sometimes changed ("different kind of snow").

Can modern TVs handle such a device (ie. I need to make more effort in tuning,)

I don't own a Printztronic Videosport 800 and know nothing about it, but in my experience with a LCD TV that has a coax input, compared to an analog TV (I still have a working one), the LCD TV is much more forgiving with respect to the timing of the video signals. After all, it only needs to drive an analog to digital converter.
However, this may differ from TV brand to brand (or even model to model), of course.

which are not easy to tune for the Prinztronic video signal.

What do you mean by "not easy to tune"? If it's RF modulated and you know the frequency/channel, you should be able to just set that.
If you don't know the frequency/channel, maybe stepping through all of them manually is the best option (plan some time for that, and let it settle before you switch), the automatic tuning may (or may not) skip over it.
And of course it's also possible that the Prinztronic video generator or RF modulator is broken, and that's the reason you don't see anything.

The part about LCDs being able to better handle weird signals because "it only needs to drive an analog to digital converter" is exactly contrary to common sense. Chips that try to sample analog signals into digital are one thing, and possibly the scaler chipset required to scale the sampled analog resolution to panel resolution is another thing. It's not just an ADC but a video decoder and these are extremely picky to anomalies in the signals. Even if they can handle the signals into some digital stream but with oddities in the sync signals, the scaler chip may not have software to detect it.

@Justme you ignored the "with respect to timing" part. I actually tried this while programming a TV encoder chip (Brooktree). Even timings outside of the standard were still detected by the digital TV and produced a stable image, while the analog TV didn't have a stable image. And yes, it's entirely according to common sense, if you understand how the digital and the analog TV process their inputs. But you are welcome to do your own experiments if you don't believe me.

I have done multiple products with multiple analog video encoders and decoders and scalers from multiple manufacturers, converting analog interfaces to digital. Back in the day, you could not even rely on Playstation 3 to output composite video without some weirdness, which I recall related to how it outputs the last half line that should transition to correct serration pulses. Chips need proper control to detect and compensate for weirdness in the signal. If you have 100% success rate by doing it once, that's a bit of statistical skew. Even pro video monitor fails to show C64 picture.

@dirkt: NTSC broadcast standards at the end of the NTSC broadcast era specified that chroma must be in one of two phases at the start of every scan line in a correct broadcast signal, and that the phase must alternate every line.  This will only be possible if scan lines are exactly the right length (less than 0.1 microseconds of deviation)--something even the cheapest DVD player could achieve, but which would be beyond the range of all but the most sophisticated video tape equipment.  Designing a digital receiver that can work well with the output of an analog consumer-grade VCR...

...is not a trivial task.  In the analog era, designing a set that wouldn't care about chroma/horizontal phase was easier than designing one which had enough precision to care.  A lot of video-generating equipment was built around the fact that sets weren't overly picky about such things.
